# Unable to import openCV in Anaconda

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I installed opencv in Anaconda - Spyder.

I am working on Ubuntu 64bit, Python 3.6 and anaconda 4.1.

I used the command below:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv=3.2.0
opencv 3.2.0 np112py36_blas_openblas_201  [blas_openblas]  conda-forge
```

But when I tried to import it in Spyder it throws error as:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'opencv'

Comment: try "import cv2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `import cv2` not `opencv`